# Email sending options when build policy fails

Tags: azure, azure-devops

Is there any way to control sending e-mails to the auto reviewers if any of the build policy conditions fails In Azure DevOps?

We are using "Azure Repos GIT". Adding conditions in Build policies.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to control sending e-mails to the auto reviewers if any of the build policy conditions fails In Azure DevOps?

The answer is yes.

You could create the **Notifications** with following filter:

[image]

To add a Notifications, go to `user settings`->`Notifications`:

[image]

Hope this helps.